# Python Pandas regex numbers in parentheses from a column to a list

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to take all the items in Data that are in a pandas dataframe column and pull out all Item A numbers in the parentheses to sum. The desired output is below for `'Item A`' would be `[0.12, 0.46, 0.45]`

```
Data = Item A (0.12);Item B (4.5);Item C (9.96);Item B (0.59);Item A (0.46);Item A (0.45);Item C (4.99);
```

[Image of the dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZCyMK.png)

I have tried `df1['output'] = df1['Raw'].str.findall(r'\s\(\d{1,2}.\d\d\)')` I believe the regex is working but I can't figure out how to get the matching numbers out.

Answer (score 0):

To find arrays for all items you can use:

```
for item in ['Item A', 'Item B']:
    df1[item] = df1['Raw'].str.findall(item+r'\s\((\d.\d*)\)')
```

**Example with your data:**

Input:

```
                                                 Raw
0  Item A (0.12);Item B (4.5);Item C (9.96);Item ...
```

Output:

```
                                                 Raw              Item A  \
0  Item A (0.12);Item B (4.5);Item C (9.96);Item ...  [0.12, 0.46, 0.45]   

        Item B  
0  [4.5, 0.59]
```

Comment: You also can add `Item C` to array to find Items C. If you have unknown amount of items you can use regular expression to find names of Items.

Comment: Just to add some clarity, there are 3 columns in the dataframe. Columns = [site, product, raw]. The string/s i'm searching for is in column raw. I would like to pull what is in () behind 'Item A (23.22) and put into another column. I hope this helps

Comment: This code searching numbers in () after Item A and put it into another  column with name Item A. After that, it searches numbers after 'Item B' and put it into column Item B etc. If you need values only for item A, you can run this code with change raw `for item in ['Item A', 'Item B']:` to `for item in ['Item A']:`